# EnableViewState not working in DropDownList

Tags: asp.net

The default.aspx page has a `DropDownList` which is populated in the code behind only when it is not a `postback`. When a value is selected a method is called which fills a `Literal` with the selected value. It works as expected. The problem is when I set the page to not `EnableViewState` enabling it in the `DropDownList` control only. In this case when posted back the `DropDownList` loses its items. I have setup a new Web project just to test this. There is no master page to make it simpler.

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication4._Default" 
    EnableViewState="false" %>

<asp:DropDownList ID="DDL" runat="server" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDL_OSIC" 
    AutoPostBack="true" 
    EnableViewState="true">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DDL.Items.Add("red");
        DDL.Items.Add("green");
        DDL.Items.Add("blue");
    }
}
protected void DDL_OSIC(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Literal1.Text = DDL.SelectedValue;
}
```

Why isn't EnableViewState working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer with the help of a deleted answer. The deleted answer was wrong just because it was incomplete. With that hint I found [the ViewStateMode Property page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstatemode.aspx).

Summarizing it to disable all controls' ViewState and enable it just for the choosen ones:

- Set both the page and all the control's `EnableViewState` property to `true`. This is the default so it is not necessary to write anything
- Set the page `ViewStateMode` to `Disabled`
- Set `ViewStateMode` to `Enabled` in the control where you want ViewState enabled

Answer (score -3):

In my computer,I create a web application.The result is same with you.
I guess,when the page viewstate is false,control viewstate can't work.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.