# DropDownList EnableViewState bug?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, viewstate, asp.net-2.0

I am using ASP.NET 2.0. I have `EnableViewState="false"` is set on master page and all my pages and have `EnableViewState="true"` is set on some controls. It works okay on `TextBox`, but `DropDownList` for unknown reason absolutely ignores local `EnableViewState="true"` and losses its values.

I have found one answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11787177/758815 , but it based on `ViewStateMode` property, which seems only appeared in ASP.NET 4.0.

Any ideas on this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Container's `EnableViewState` setting overrides any child control `EnableViewState` setting, so if it is set to `false` at page level setting it to `true` on any of the control has no effect.

Not sure why it works on the TextBox, perhaps it's not a part of the hierarchy.

Comment: Unfortunately, you are correct. I've dug around and found same info. Do you know will it work if I enable it on page level and disable on heavy items like `Repeaters`?

Comment: Now that's the way to go. Enable it (or rather leave default) on the top level, but disable it on controls that don't really need it. Be careful tho, some controls (e.g. grids with paging) may need viewstate to function normally